# Generate question label based on the number of options available as answers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a report where I need to show the results of a survey. For questions with options as available answers I need to generate one row by option to create a label for that question, but some questions have a limited number of options that user can select.

This is my DB schema:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    ID   |   Question    |   Sequence     | MaxNoAnswers |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |    Question 1 |              1 |            2 |
|       2 |    Question 2 |              2 |         NULL | 
-----------------------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
|OptionID |   Name        |  QuestionID    | Sequence |
-------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |    Option 1   |              1 |        1 |
|       2 |    Option 2   |              1 |        2 |
|       3 |    Option 3   |              1 |        3 |
|       4 |    Option 4   |              1 |        4 |
|       5 |    Option 5   |              2 |        1 |
|       6 |    Option 6   |              2 |        2 |
|       7 |    Option 7   |              2 |        3 |
|       8 |    Option 8   |              2 |        4 |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to label each question concatenating the Question ID with the Sequence of the option, for example:

```
SELECT 'Q' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), q.[ID]) + '_' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), o.Sequence) AS QuestionLabel, q.Question 
FROM Question q
INNER JOIN Options o ON o.QuestionID = q.ID
```

Result of this will be:

```
-----------------------------------
|  QuestionLabel  |   Question    | 
-----------------------------------
|    Q1_1         |    Question 1 |
|    Q1_2         |    Question 1 | 
|    Q1_3         |    Question 1 |
|    Q1_4         |    Question 1 | 
|    Q2_1         |    Question 2 |
|    Q2_2         |    Question 2 | 
|    Q2_3         |    Question 2 |
|    Q2_4         |    Question 2 | 
-----------------------------------
```

But if there is a MaxNoAnswers set I need to generate only one label from 1 to the number of MaxNoAnswers like this:

```
-----------------------------------
|  QuestionLabel  |   Question    | 
-----------------------------------
|    Q1_1         |    Question 1 |
|    Q1_2         |    Question 1 | 
|    Q2_1         |    Question 2 |
|    Q2_2         |    Question 2 | 
|    Q2_3         |    Question 2 |
|    Q2_4         |    Question 2 | 
-----------------------------------
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: add a `WHERE` clause to your query `WHERE o.Sequence <= q.MaxNoAnswers OR q.MaxNoAnswers IS NULL`

Comment: Will Question 2 actually have rows in the Option table? If so, what prevents you from only including MaxNoAnswers rows for that QuestionID?